# Printer Line break not works properly using Java

Tags: java, printing, network-printers

Here is the code I used to Print a String using java

```
String string2 = "    RECEIPT    \n==============\nHeader2\nHeader 3\nLine 4 Goes Here\nLine 5 Goes Here\n============";

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(string2.getBytes());
DocFlavor flavor =  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE   ;

// Find the default service
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
System.out.println(service);

// Create the print job
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
Doc doc= new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

// Print it
job.print(doc, null);

pjDone.waitForDone();

// It is now safe to close the input stream
is.close();
```

It is printing on the paper like.

```
 RECEIPT    
        ============== 
                      Header2
                             Header 3
                                     Line 4 Goes Here
                                                     Line 5 Goes Here
```

Same happens when using inputStream without a String. Any Suggestion plz. And need an explanation how this DocFlavor working.Thanks

Comment: try with `\r\n`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\r\n` instead of `\r`.

There is two ASCII code `\n` "line feed". It tell the printer to move to next line. And `\r` "carriage return" it  to move carriage  to beginning of the line.

Comment: To the beginning of the *line*.